# Black screen when switching user & gfx issues with Chromium

Tags: ati, 15.10, amd-processor

Now that fglrx finally supports 15.10, I switched the driver to fglrx-updates. However, now I have at least two new issues which are not present with open source drivers:

- After switching user the display often remains black
- There is a lot of graphical glitches with Chromium

I have AMD A10-7800 APU.